# AR(1) to Ornstein-Uhlenbeck for AR(1) process of the form $\ln z_{t+1}=\rho \ln z_t+\sigma \sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}\epsilon_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, vector-auto-regression

I have the AR(1) process of the following form:

$$\ln z_{t+1}=\rho \ln z_t+\sigma \sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}\epsilon_t$$

And need to find its continous time corresponding Ornstein-Uhlenbeckprocess.

I have the info that an AR(1) can be translated to an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck as follows:
$$dx=\theta(\bar{x}-x)dt+\sigma dW \tag{O-U}$$
$$x_{t+1}=\theta\bar{x}+(1-\theta)x_t +\sigma\epsilon_t\tag{AR(1)}$$
but fail to see how to apply this to this specific case. I have looked at other answers considering the translation between AR(1) and OU, but again do not clearly see it for this specific form.

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

edit:
Using the answer below and a linear approximation of $e^{-\theta \Delta}\approx1-\theta \Delta$ and setting $\Delta=1$ I get
$$d\ln z_t=-(1-\rho) \ln z_t +\sigma \sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}dW_t$$
which corresponds to the approximation as given by (AR(1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve

$$dx=\theta(\bar{x}-x)ds+\sigma dW_s $$

by multiplying by an integrating factor $e^{\theta s}$ and integrating over $[t,t+\Delta]$ to obtain

$$e^{\theta(t+\Delta)}x(t + \Delta) - e^{\theta t}x(t) = \bar{x} ( e^{\theta(t + \Delta)}- e^{\theta t}) + \sigma\int_t^{t + \Delta} e^{\theta s}\, dW_s$$

Rearranging we get,

$$\tag{*}x(t + \Delta) =\bar{x}(1 - e^{-\theta \Delta}) + e^{-\theta \Delta}x(t)  + \underbrace{\sigma e^{-\theta \Delta}\int_t^{t + \Delta} e^{\theta(s- t)}\, dW_s}_{I(t,\Delta)}$$

The moments of the stochastic integral on the RHS are

$$\mathbb{E}\left(I(t, \Delta) \right) = 0, \\ var\left(I(t, \Delta) \right)= \sigma^2 e^{-2\theta \Delta}\int_t^{t + \Delta} e^{2\theta(s- t)}\, ds = \frac{\sigma^2(1 - e^{-2\theta \Delta})}{2 \theta}$$

Thus, we can write (*) as

$$x(t + \Delta) =\bar{x}(1 - e^{-\theta \Delta}) + e^{-\theta \Delta}x(t)  + \sigma\sqrt{\frac{1 - e^{-2\theta \Delta}}{2\theta}}\xi,$$

where $\xi \sim N(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable.

Making the association with your AR(1) process we have

$$x(t+\Delta) \iff \ln z_{t+1} \quad x(t) \iff \ln z_t, \\ \bar{x} = 0, \quad \rho = e^{-\theta \Delta}, \quad \sigma\sqrt{1- \rho^2} \iff \sigma\sqrt{\frac{1 - e^{-2\theta \Delta}}{2\theta}}$$

So the continuous time process is

$$d \ln z_t = \frac{\ln \rho}{\Delta}\ln z_t \,dt + \sigma \sqrt{\frac{-\ln \rho}{\Delta}} \, dW_t$$

where $\Delta$ is the time interval between sampled observations.

Comment: just for notational consistency, how would you get rid of $\Delta$ so that I only have "dt" terms?

Comment: It's just a matter of using a dimensionless time variable $\hat{t} = t/\Delta$

Comment: Or I could have integrated the SDE over the interval $[t,t+1]$ and it goes away.

Comment: the 2nd solution speaks to my small minded economist tunnel vision

Comment: So I left out the $dt$ in the answer by mistake -- I now added it.Clearly you can see how $\Delta$ can be absorbed into the time variable.  Also the Wiener process is $\mathcal{O}(dt)$ which is why the $\sqrt{\Delta}$ shows up as a coefficient.  Short answer -- just set $\Delta = 1$.

Comment: can it basically be absorbed by considering the integral from 0 to $t$ rather than 0 to $\Delta$ or how is it to be understood?

Comment: First be aware that when you write the difference equation for a discrete AR(1) process with constant parameters as you have done then it is implicit that the observations are a regularly spaced intervals. I'm assuming that the innovation $\epsilon_t$ is a stationary standard normal random variable  with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.  If you are now contemplating irregularly spaced intervals then the parameters have to depend on index (i.e, time) unless you have a very weird situation.  There is some fundamental unit of time $\Delta$ such that $t_k - t_{k-1} - \Delta$.

Comment: sure :-) so I would say that I would consider basically infinitely small movements in the OU - i.e. in the way I am going to implement it, I need to solve for it by Ito's formula and basically just use an analytical solution. The reason I am a bit confused is that in the original expression, going between AR(1) and OU that I posted in the question (i.e. from my lecture) they got away with a translation without having any $\Delta$

Comment: We can say $\Delta = 1$ if you like, but if you mean, for example $t_2=t_1 + 1$ and $t_3 = t_2 + 2$, then the standard deviation of $\epsilon_2$ has to be larger than that of $\epsilon_1$ by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I am not thinking in those terms, just how in all lectures and litterature that I use $\Delta$ never appears in the O-U. So for example, how would I show that $dx=\theta(\bar{x}-x)dt+\sigma dW \tag{O-U}$ and $x_{t+1}=\theta\bar{x}+(1-\theta)x_t +\sigma\epsilon_t\tag{AR(1)}$ are alike (in other words go from the AR(1) to OU here where they have the same parameters). In the method you showed, I always get the $\Delta$ dependence

Comment: Of course it does not appear in the continuous time equation but the time variable $t$ has some unit attached to it -- say years.  this means $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the change over a year.  If your discrete sampling is on trading days (where 1 year equals 252 trading days) then the standard deviation over one discrete step has to be $\sigma/\sqrt{252}$.

Comment: sure thing :-) so my question is basically of purely theoretical interest I guess, so how can I arrive at a continous time equation exactly like the O-U posted from an AR

Comment: If $t$ in the continuous process means time in years and your discrete sample spacing is daily then there has to be a factor of $\Delta = 1/252$ appearing in your discrete process to relate the parameters correctly.

Comment: The  OU and AR(1) you wrote with the same parameters $\theta$ and $\sigma$ appearing in both is only correct if the spacing between discrete steps is the same as the time unit for $t$, e.g. 1 year.

Comment: I see that, and that is useful. The problem is that I am not even asked to think about this, I am just asked to write out an equation on the exact same form as $dx=\theta(\bar{x}-x)ds+\sigma dW_s $ and I am not quite sure I get how your answer corresponds to that, or if we are doing something different (and still correct but just not like this)

Comment: - in answer to your last comment, that is good to know and exactly what I was after

Comment: I just noticed - for your discretization to fit the equations (AR(1)) and (OU) in my original answer, one has to linearly approximate $e^{-\theta\Delta}\approx 1-\theta \Delta$ and additionally integrate from t to t+1, i.e. $\Delta=1$.